# Authenticated user cannot view custom content type pages

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have a new Drupal 8 website which only two of us have login access to. I'm the administrator and the other person is an authenticated user. I've set the permissions so that authenticated users can see/edit/delete/etc. all the custom content types. In this case, I have a custom content type for our library branches. When this person logs in, she gets Access Denied when she goes to the library branch pages. What else should I be checking? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying they get access denied on the front end of the page, e.g. /node/123? or when they try to edit the page, e.g. node/123/edit?

Comment: When she views /node/123 she gets Access Denied. Weird, right?